# Почему не происходит авто-обновление списка ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть такой список формируемый `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="friend in friends"></div>
```

Когда я удаляю элемент из массива `friends`:

```
delete $scope.friends[id];
```

тогда мой исходный список не обновляется, т-е удаленный элемент div не скрывается сразу. Скрывается, если сделать клик по зоне `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во первых проверьте что используете `ng-click`
Во вторых лутчий способ по удалению элемента с массива `splice`.
Найти индекс текущего элемента

```
var index = arr.indexOf(element)
```

Удалить с текущего интекса 1 елементЖ

```
arr.splice(index, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте встроенные в angular директивы (ng-click и т.д) для вызова ваших обработчиков. Вы так же можете принудительно вызвать обновление связанных данных используя $scope.$apply(). Но лучше использовать уже имеющиеся в angular директивы и сервисы т.к. они эффективнее работают с обновлением данных.

Comment: Для удаления элемента из массива я использую `ng-click`. При этом список не обновляется

Answer (score 0):

Для удаления элементов из массива я использую метод splice. Вот пример - http://plnkr.co/edit/Gp6GhuALHGmayp6IhSE3?p=preview